# Oracle database connection string PLSQL compatibility

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, connection-string

I'm using an application called Logi info. it requires a connection string to my oracle database. the connection works fine but in order to configure the connection to recive ref cursors from the database, [I apparently need to add](http://www.logixml.com/DevNet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1008&dnProd=&IdeDisplayStatus=Collapsed#ConnString) `PLSQLRSet=1` to the end of the string. when I do that I recieve an error "invalid connection string"

Here is my connection string without plsqlrset=1

```
Data Source=SID; User Id=username; Password=password;
```

My concern is that `PLSQLRSet=1` might be .NET paramater only. Can anyone shed some light on the issue.

Thanks

Comment: how do you want to connect to the dabase? jdbc,..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `PLSQLRset` option is a feature of the OraOLEDB provider (per http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95498/using.htm).

Therefore I would guess that you have to add `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle` to the connect string -- as shown in the screenshot on the page you linked to -- in order to use this option.